# Unable to locate element using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am using the UIAutomation library from Microsoft for C#. I have an element with the following properties:

- LocalizedControlType: "edit"
- AutomationId: "Database"
- Readonly: False
- Text field

I am able to read these properties using Inspect. However, I am unable to find it with the following command in C#:

```
AutomationElement ae = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Database"), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "edit"));
```

In fact, the only way I can find it is via the following command (which follows the tree):

```
AutomationElement ae = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[2]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[2]
                    .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0];
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to edit the value, I am hit with an error message that the selected element is read only. However, the element is in fact not read-only. Also, the element does not have the automationId that it should have. None of the elements in the tree have an AutomationId when viewed with the UIAutomation.

The application that I am attempting to automate is a proprietary application, and this is the first time I've had this issue. I'm not sure what might be causing this, what would be something I could look into?

EDIT: Just as an update, I was able to successfully locate the elements required using indexing from root.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition).

However, I have the following code:

```
        cachedElement = findAll[index];
        Console.Write("cachedelement : "); cachedElement.ToConsole();           
        return 0;
```

If I just let the program run, it fails when it tries to write the text to the text field. Also, it shows that the selected element has no attributes (during the cachedelement.ToConsole).

Interestingly, if I put a breakpoint on return 0; (or use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()), cachedElement.ToConsole() outputs the LCT as "edit" (still no automationId), and writes the text to the text field properly. Why I find this interesting, is that the breakpoint is set after the call to ToConsole. It shouldn't have an effect on the running code at all.

Comment: As it turns out, I never figured out why the field is missing automationId, however it looks like elements were being added to the tree upon editing. I've wrote a small function that starts at a given known index, then looks based on the element's localized control type. This appears to be a good work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second code example the element you are looking for is nested pretty far down the tree so the first code example will never find the element because it is only looking at children of the desktop. If you want to look for the element from the root node you would need to use [TreeScope.Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treescope(v=vs.110).aspx) for the treescope. I don't recommend using descendants though because it will be slow and more than likely it will cause a [stack overflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) when used from the root element.

In the worst case scenario I do a FindFirst for my window using child scope from the root element then I use descendants from the applications root. This only works quickly though on small applications with trivial users interfaces. If you have something complex like a grid with cells I would suggest using FindFirst with child scope all the way down to the element you are looking for similar to how you used the find all.

If you can post the code you are using to edit the element I can update this answer with information on how to edit the control that is specific to your situation. In general though how you would edit a text box control would be to use the [ValuePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.valuepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) like this.

```
  public void SetValue(AutomationElement element, string text)
  {
        var valuePattern = (ValuePattern) element.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern);
        valuePattern.SetValue(text);
  }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I did end up setting it to Descendants in my edit. I ended up creating a work around to search based off a base index then by localizedcontroltype as that's the only option I have (AutomationId is missing only in C#'s UIAutomation. I can see it in Inspect). So for now, my issue is resolved but I'm still curious as to why not all of the attributes show properly.